# We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity
firebase sent this error when the user logs in to my app for the first time!!
and I changed my Firebase Spark Plan (free) to Blaze Plan (Pay as you go) but the problem isn't solved.

Comment: If you have upgrade your plan, then you're entitled to the customer support, ask them what to do

Comment: @MohamedSaleh Are you using phone number authentication? And are you frequently logging in via same number?

Comment: @Martheen Firebase offers support to developer on its free plan too. There is no need to upgrade before [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya no no the user registers on the app for the first time and enters the number for the first time , this error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Firebase enables apps with a Phone Authentication feature. But, when you/others are testing your application, you might have received the following error:

> We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity.
> Try again later.

This error usually occurs when Firebase has received too many OTPs within a short period. And we need to have to wait for an hour to start using the Phone Authentication feature again.

Firebase has a feature to add test numbers. So, it's address under:

```
Firebase Console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method -> Phone.
```

Now, you can use the "Phone numbers for testing" section to add test phone numbers. These test numbers are never going to be blocked by Firebase. You can also use the test numbers for the Apple Approval process when publishing your app, but this is not confirmed yet.